# Why can't I get the value of this text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have a div, which contains a text input field:

```
<div id="age" class="fullScreen">
  <input type="text" id="age" class="textInput" placeholder="Please enter age..." />
  <button type="button" onclick="submitAge()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

submitAge() looks like this:

```
function submitAge() {
  var ageVal = document.getElementById("age").text;
  alert(ageVal);
}
```

But in Google Chrome and Webkit Nightly I see an alert with the text "undefined" (I can't test in any other browsers because the page contains web-sockets).

The chrome developer tools show this:

[image: ageVal: undefined]

I assume that the problem is that the input is not in a form, but I don't want it to be in a form because I will be submitting the data via websockets.

Do I have to put it in a form or is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You have 2 HTML elements with ID = age

Comment: Not going to post yet another answer because between all the other answers you have your two problems, but #1 you can't have more than one element with the same ID, the behavior is undefined.  #2 you need `value` not `text`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have redefined the id "age".  Rename either your div or input and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
function submitAge() {
  var ageVal = document.getElementById("age").value;
  alert(ageVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ageVal = document.getElementById('age').value;

alert(ageVal)
```

Note the .value instead of text

Comment: Still doesn't work... I had already tried that and just tried it again.

Comment: Hum i guess you have noticed by now that the error was the double tags with the same id

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 var ageVal = document.getElementById("age").text;
```

to

```
 var ageVal = document.getElementById("age").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getDocumentById("age").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You `<div>` has the id of age. This is going to return either the div or an array of HTMLElements. Get a **unique** id of the input and you will be golden